# What does this "IDP.SideLoad.Applaunch3" virus do?

Tags: anti-virus

I am running Windows 10. I recently installed Avast antivirus. It kept one file in quarantine:
**MoUSO.exe** because of "IDP.SideLoad.Applaunch3":

[image]

Google gave irrelevant results on this virus.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDP means IDentity Protection. [Sideloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sideloading), in this context, is installing stuff from "non-official" sources. MoUSO is the Microsoft [Update Session Orchestrator](https://superuser.com/a/1650621/1482432).

If you suspect it is a false-positive, upload it to the [false positive form](https://www.avast.com/false-positive-file-form.php) on the Avast website.

Avast isn't very good at detecting viruses (and determining which files are safe). You can check if other virus scanners agree with it by uploading the file to [virustotal.com](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/). It will be scanned with a bunch of different scanners.